# Partitioning a loop into unique tasks using OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

Please excuse me if this question has been answered before, I cannot figure out which are the right keywords.

I want to run in parallel a lot of calls to linux commands  using openmp. I need to guarantee in some how, that each worker wait until the command finish and the command can take different time to finish. To simplify the issue, I am trying to generate  the names of the files on which the command will run but each file name is been generated more than once, but the names of the file are unique.  how can I modify the following lines of code to achieve   an unique call by file  name (Therefore a unique call to the command) using OpenMP?

```
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
    #pragma omp parallel for  private(command, dirname) shared(i_traj) schedule(dynamic)
       for(i_traj=0; i_traj<G.size(); i_traj++)
        {
   //command will contain the comand line. 
          snprintf(dirname1,sizeof(dirname1), "ID%i_Trajectory_%i",ID,G[i_traj].ID);
          dirname = string(dirname1);
          /*Initializing the trajectories*/

          cout<<"Going to: "<<G[i_traj].folder_addr<<endl;
        }
```

This section of the code will be executed in a fuction and not in the main program. Is possible to do the same using MPICH2?

**UPDATE:**
The problem has to do with my computer rather than with the code because the code works properly using another machine. Any suggestion?

UPGRADE:

Trying to follow the reccomendations of Gilles, I upgraded the code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define LARGE_NUMBER 100
double item[LARGE_NUMBER];
void process(int ID, nucleus &tr)
{
  char dirname1[40];
  string command;
  string script_folder;
  snprintf(dirname1,sizeof(dirname1), "ID%i_Trajectory_%i",ID,tr.ID);
  string dirname;
  dirname = string(dirname1);
  /*Initializing the trajectories*/
  cout<<"Running: "<<dirname<<endl;
  script_folder = "./"+ dirname;
  chdir(script_folder.c_str());
  //command = "qsub " + dirname+"_PBS"  + ".sh";                                                                                                                                                
  command = "gamess-2013 " + dirname + ".inp  01  1 ";

  printf ("Checking if processor is available...");
  if (system(NULL)) puts ("Ok");
  else exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  if(!tr.runned)
    {
      int fail= system(command.c_str());
      tr.runned=true;
    }

  chdir("../");
  return;
}

int main() {

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<LARGE_NUMBER; i++)
#pragma omp task
        // i is firstprivate, item is shared                                                                                                                                                    
        process(i);
    }

  }
 return 0;
}
```

But the problem of guarantee that each file is processed only once remains. How can I be sure that each task works on a unique file, waiting until the command execution is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I really don't understand neither the question you ask, nor its context. This sentence especially puzzles me a lot:

> To simplify the issue, I am trying to generate the names of the files on which the command will run but each file name is been generated more than once, but the names of the file are unique.

Anyway, all that to say that my answer is likely to just miss the point. However, I still can report that your code snippet has a major issue: you explicitly declare `shared` the index `i_traj` of the loop that you try to parallelise. This makes no sense, since if there is one variable you want to be `private` in an OpenMP parallel loop, this is the loop index. Moreover, the OpenMP standard explicitly forbids it [section 2.14.1.1](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf#G4.1582732). (emphasis are mine)

> The **loop iteration variable(s)** in the associated for-loop(s) of a for
>   or parallel for construct is (are) **private**.
>   [...]
>   Variables with predetermined data-sharing attributes may not be listed
>   in data-sharing attribute clauses, except for the cases listed below.
>   **For these exceptions only, listing a predetermined variable in a
>   data-sharing attribute clause is allowed and overrides the variable’s
>   predetermined data-sharing attributes.**

Follows a list of exceptions where making `shared` the "loop iteration variable(s)" is not mentioned.

So again, my answer might just completely miss the point, but you definitely have a problem here, which you'd better fix before to try to go any deeper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  attempting to take into account your observations,  I edited the question adding code for  a safer approach.